# Android tablet disconnects from wifi every ten minutes

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, 8.1-oreo

I have a Galaxy Tab A Wifi only version (SM-T580), running Android 8.1.0. It is unrooted.

Every ten or fifteen minutes or so, the wifi drops out. After about 30 seconds or so, it reconnects. No other device on my network has this issue.

Less frequently, the Bluetooth connection drops out, which I suspect might be an associated issue. I usually have the tablet connected to Bluetooth speakers, and every now and the sound will cut out for about twenty seconds, then return.

I have searched online for solutions, and the general advice is to switch from DHCP to static, which I have done. Beyond that I can't get any more specific information.

Is there any kind of test I can run to determine why this is happening?

Comment: Logs should help find information about whats going on. Through a command prompt throw the command: (linux) `adb logcat -v long > ~/Desktop/logcat.txt` (windows) adb logcat -v long > %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt thats a standard verbose logcat. Radio logs might also show some insight witht he command: `adb logcat -b radio -v time -d > logcat_radio.log` along with `adb shell dumpsys wifi` those commands should put a file on your desktop if not just copy the terminal and paste it to any pasting site such as pastebin, hastebin, or whatever then edit and attach them to your post for feedback.

Comment: @BoLawson, thanks for these commands, but I'm unsure where to run them. I no longer have a Linux computer, only Windows. Is there a way I can connect my Android to my Windows computer to run these commands?

Comment: Ye yo can, i included the windoes commands too. You just have to install adb through the Android SDK-Platform-tools onto your pc. Then you can open a cmd prompt to throw the above mentioned commands. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: Windows commands: `(windows) adb logcat -v long > %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt ` thats a verbose logcat. `adb logcat -b radio -v time -d > logcat_radio.log` radio logcat. `adb shell dumpsys wifi` thats a dump of wifi stuff.

Comment: @BoLawson, Thank you for your help. I've downloaded the Android SDK and connected my tablet by USB, but when I run any of the commands, I get `error: no devices/emulators found`. Is there something else I need to do to create the conditions to run a test that will reveal some answers?

Comment: You need to enable USB Debugging if you have not done so yet. You so by going into `Settings --> About Phone --> scroll to the bottom --> tap Build number seven (7) times.` A short pop-up in the lower area of your display saying that you're now a developer. 2. Go back and now access the Developer options menu, check `USB Debugging`and click OK. The when you connect to your computer and an RSA pop-you should appear. Now just press OK ad you should be good to Go.

Comment: @BoLawson, thank you for your instructions, and sorry that I'm going slowly on this, but I just can't seem to get any kind of connection. I've enabled USB debugging as you described. Then at the command line I start one of the adb commands, and it says `waiting for device`. I've tried connecting and reconnecting my tablet a few times, and turning USB debugging on and off, but nothing seems to happen anywhere. Is there some driver or something I need to install or some other missing step?

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark, but according to one site, you can try turning off the "disconnect on sleep" option.

> Check your Keep WiFi on during sleep options. These allow you to specify when to disconnect from WiFi.
>
> Go to Home > Apps > Settings > WiFi > more >Keep WiFi on during sleep. Hopefully you can stop it from disconnecting at all by choosing an option .

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/280849/Tablet+loses+wifi+connection

There are other models that lose connectivity based on how you hold it or due to an old update, but these are significantly different models that shouldn't anything to do with your model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, on my tablet's interface there is no option for controlling "sleep" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

Settings>Connections>Data Usage>Restrict Networks

Select your wifi connection

Select not metered

Done